# Why is "necessary p" true in a world when there is no world accessible from it?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

So my question is situated in modal logic and everything is defined as usual. I'm reading volume 2 of logic, language, and meaning and on page 24 it says:

$V_{M,w_3}(\square p)= 1$

So the valuation function determined by the model makes the formula $\square p$ true at $w_3$. And this is their explanation: "since there are no worlds at all which are accessible from $w_3$ (so that p is true in all of the [nonexistent] worlds which are accessible)."

So they seem to be saying that if a world has no other world accessible from it a formula like $\square p$ is always true? Am I interpreting this right and if so then why is this true?

Comment: Yes.  Keyword: *vacuous truth*.  Since there is no accessible world where $p$ can be false, it is true in all accessible worlds.

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast. I understand it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword is *vacuous truth*

Since there is no accessible world where $p$ can be false, it is true in all accessible worlds.   Thus it is necessary. $$V_{M,w_3}( \Box p )=1$$

---

On the other hand, since there is no accessible world where $p$ can be true, it is not true in any accessible world.   Thus it is *also* not possible. $$V_{M,w_3}( \Diamond p )=0$$